Microsoft Surface Laptop 7 with Snapdragon Elite processor and inability to set a Bitlocker PIN startup
I have just purchased a Surface Laptop 7 and enabled Bitlocker. I now want to configure a startup PIN for Bootlocker.
I have followed this MVPs advice to do so (https://www.kapilarya.com/enable-bitlocker-pin-in-windows-11). (I had to set "Require Startup PIN with TPM" though when editing the group policy.
This then does give the option in Manage Bitlocker to create a startup PIN.
But then it fails with this error: "ERROR: An error occurred (code 0x803100b5): No pre-boot keyboard detected. The user may not be able to provide required input to unlock the volume."
The Surface Laptop 7 does have an inbuilt keyboard of course, I am typing on it now! It is a traditional "clamshell" laptop.
I have of course researched this issue in depth and know about the "slate" group policy setting etc.
Does anybody please know how (or if) I may achieve my aim to set a Bitlocker PIN successfully?
Thank you.
